# Why does "jack" occur in so many different contexts?

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrase-meaning

The word "Jack" is not only a name, but "jack" is also a verb with versatile meanings depending on prepositions and context.

- to jack
- to jack sth. up
- to jack sth. in
- to jack through
- to jack up a price
- to jack into place
- to get jack of sth.
- ...

and I did not include the vulgar examples. In addition, there are many meanings as a noun:

- playing card
- plug (electricity)
- jack boot
- jack bush
- jack head
- ...

This lists are far from complete.

**I wonder why this particular word has so many different meanings, and if there is an answer to this question.**

The name Jack appears to be of French origin ("Jaque"), but that certainly does not explain all of the above items.

Comment: Because it's a jack of all trades.

Comment: Just a normal distribution. When you have a million words, some of them are bound to have more meanings than others. And if you think that a dozen meanings count as "many", please do not look up *set, go, get, run, turn, take* or *put*.

Comment: Because of its etymological history: https://www.etymonline.com/word/jack

Comment: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-jac3.htm Not to be missed.

Comment: A question I've often wondered about too.  There's also jack fish, a term used for different fish in different regions but in my experience always a large predator.   It's also used with professions: lumber jack for example.  Yeats once wrote a line that goes "Malachi stilt jack am I".

Answer (score 4):

The first meaning of the noun, ***[jack](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jack)***, listed by Oxford Dictionaries, is a device used for lifting heavy weights, loads, merchandise, etc. Today the most common form is a *car jack*, *floor jack* or *garage jack*, used by car owners and professional car mechanics to lift vehicles in order to change tires or perform repairs. The first attestation in the Oxford English Dictionary of *jack* in the sense 'a machine, usually portable, for lifting heavy weights by force acting from below' is from 1679.

From *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_(given_name)#Other_uses_in_English)*

> - The name Jack is unusual in the English language for its frequent use as a noun or verb for many common objects and actions, and in many compound words and phrases.
> - Examples include a *car jack*, the game *jacks* or the *jack* in bowls.
> - The word is also used in other words and phrases such as: *apple jack*, *hijack*, *jack of clubs* (playing card), *jack straw* (scarecrow), *jack tar* (sailor), *jack-in-the-box*, *jack-of-all-trades*, *jack o'lantern*, *jackdaw*, *jackhammer*, *jackknife*, *jackpot*, *lumberjack*, *union jack* (the British flag), etc.
> - **The history of the word is linked to the name being used as a by-name for a man**

**Etymology**

From Middle English *jakke* (“a term of familiarity or contempt; guy; a [mechanical turnspit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roasting_jack); a brass coin”), from the name ***Jack***.

> **The proper name was used in Middle English for "any common fellow," and thereafter extended to various appliances which do the work of common servants (1570s)**.
>
> masc. proper name, attested by 1218, probably via Anglo-French *Jake*, *Jaikes*, from Old French *Jacques* (which was a diminutive of Latin *Jacobus*), but in English the name always has been regarded as a familiar form of John, and some have argued that it is a native formation.
>
> In Middle English spelled *Jakke*, *Jacke*, etc., and pronounced as two syllables ("Jackie")
>
> ### **jack** (verb)
>
> 1860, jack up "hoist, raise, lift with a jack," American English, from *jack* (n.) in the appliance sense. Figurative sense "increase (prices, etc.)" is 1904, American English. Related: *Jacked*; *jacking*. *Jack off* (v.) "masturbate" is attested from 1916, probably from jack (n.) in the old slang sense of "(erect) penis."
>
> *[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jack)*

Nouns and *verbs* derived from *J/jack*

> [jackass](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jackass), jackball, jackboot, [jackdaw](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jackdaw), jackfish, applejack, blackjack,  [flapjack](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=flapjack), [hijack](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hijack), jackanapes, jackaroo, [jacket](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jacket), jack-hammer, [*jack in*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jack_in#English), jack-in-the-box, [jack-knife](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jack-knife), jack-o'-lantern, jackman, jackpot, *[jack off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jack_off)*, [*jack-up*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jack_up#English), jack-shit, [jackstraw](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=jackstraw), jock, jockey, john, [lumberjack](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=lumberjack), natterjack, skipjack, steeplejack, union jack

Answer (score 2):

Your Jack is pretty similar to Joe and John.

---

The John= bathroom

A John Doe = an unidentified body.

A John = a prostitute's client.

A cup of Joe = coffee.

A sloppy Joe = a hamburger.

your average Joe = a standard/normal guy.

etc.

I guess very common names make for very common expressions.

Though many examples of yours derive from the verb jack and not from the proper noun Jack.

Comment: This seems to be a uniquely American use of these words?

Comment: That is correct, sir/